# Two datasets SQL query in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to display a grid inside a grid on my asp page.
I have two datasets for that, the main, and the sub

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="mainDS"
SelectCommand="SELECT [client_ID], [client_Name],[client_Phone],
[client_Description],[client_Devices_Type],[client_Remarks],
[client_Email] FROM [Client_Company]"

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="subDS" .........
SelectCommand="SELECT [cp_ID], [cp_Name], [cp_Phone], [cp_Email] 
FROM [contact_Person] WHERE [cp_companyID]=?????? "
```

`cp_companyID` is the foreign key from `client_ID` and I need to select only the contact persons related to the client, 
what I have shows all contact persons of all clients

how can I link the two?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `DataSource` parameters - perhaps a `ControlParameter` - depending on how you are selecting the company to show contacts for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: it worked, didn't have to go through any of this though. thanks anyways!